# Irregular plurals. Leathermans or Leathermen?

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis, irregular, i-mutation

Which plural do you use for a word that should have a regular plural but ends with a word that has its own irregular one? The example that made me ask was "leatherman" (the multitool) but there are  plenty of others.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWOo.png

Comment: Ford Focus (Focuses? Foci? Focii?) and Toyota Prius (Priuses? Prii?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it's up to the company, but nobody cares what the company says.

The official plural of *Walkman* according to Sony is *Walkman Personal Stereos*, not **Walkmans* or **Walkmen*. People widely use *walkmans* nonetheless.

Since *Leatherman* refers to a brand name and not a specific product, there probably is no official plural—even though *Leatherman* is used quite often colloquially to refer to a Leatherman-brand multitool. But people say *Leathermans* nonetheless. Seeing a pattern?

One more amusing example: *Bluetooth* is used colloquially on its own to refer to a *Bluetooth* phone headset; a cursory Googling shows *Bluetooths* dominated by Bluetooth-related results, while *Blueteeth* gives mixed results, including a number of shoddily edited product sites, one of which claimed that the “pecifications” of a phone include “blueteeth”.

So that's something.

Comment: Bluetooth is also named after a person of course

Comment: @Martin: Man, I learn something new every day because of StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is-
If the compound word is a type of the base noun, pluralize as the irregular. Otherwise pluralize the compoud as a regular noun.
Fireman becomes firemen
Walkman would become Walkmans
Leatherman would become leathermans.
Of course trademark names are not subject to the usual rules.

Answer (score -1):

In this case the tool is named after a Mr Leatherman - so it's a 'leatherman tool' (sing) or 'leatherman tools' (plural).

Comment: No. The question was what is the plural of "Leatherman". "Leatherman tools" is not the plural of "Leatherman", it is the plural of "Leatherman tool", which is a different noun phrase. Refusing to answer a question about usage by denying its premises is pointless: as with Walkmans, people are going to say it whether somebody thinks they shouldn't or not.

Comment: So the question is what do you call Mr Leatherman and his family? The leathermans presumably

Comment: Yes. Or *humorously* "the Leathermen".

Comment: @ColinFine John Gordon uses *leathermen* in [The Giant Under the Snow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giant_Under_The_Snow) but they were creepy tree-like beings (see pic in link), not multitools!